# simple while loop calculator

Tags: c++

Hello im stuck at SUBTRACTION AND DIVITION AND I CANT FIGURE OUT WHAT CODE to use because when I try to subtract 10 i inputed it then it will loop since the while condition is not meet which it needs to be negative to terminate the loop and i inputed 2 for the second number then loop again then i putted -number which lead to terminate loop and subtract all the number but the result is -12 its always wrong in every number cant figure out why Please help
Also with divition, only my addition is working havent started the divition cuz i cant figure out how

````
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
                        
int  amt2, total;
double subNumbers();
double amt=1;
double number=0;
int main() {
int chc=0;
    int amt = 0;
    int amt2 = 1;
    
    cout << "Welcome again User!\n";
    cout << "______________________________________________________________\n" << endl;
    cout << "Mathematical Operations(Improved):\n\n";
    
    cout << "\t[1]-Addition" << endl;
    cout << "\t[2]-Subtraction" << endl;    
    cout << "\t[3]-Multiplication" << endl;
    cout << "\t[4]-Division\n" << endl;    
    
    cout << "______________________________________________________________\n" << endl;
    
    cout << "Type the number corresponding to your chosen operation: ";
    cin >> chc;
```
  switch (chc) {    
  case 1:
``` 
    system ("cls");
    
    cout << "\n\n\tOperation chosen: Addition";
    
    cout << "\n______________________________________________________________" << endl;
    
    cout << "\n\nInput positive numbers to use the operation and input a negative number to end the operation.\n\n";
    
    cout << "Enter your number: ";`
    cin >> number;
    
    while (number >= 0) {
        // add all positive numbers
        amt += number;
        
        // take input again if the number is positive
        cout << "Enter another number: ";
        cin >> number;
    }
    
        // display the sum
    cout << "\nThe sum of all the numbers is: " << amt << endl;
    break; 
```
  case 2:  
    system ("cls");
    cout << "\n\n\tOperation chosen: Subtraction";
    

  
    cout << "\n______________________________________________________________" << endl;
    
    cout << "\n\nInput positive numbers to use the operation and input a negative number to end the operation.\n\n";
    do{
    
    cout << "Enter your number: ";
    cin >> number;
    amt=number-number ; 


  

    
    }while (number >= 0);// subtract all positive numbers
      
        
    
    
        // display the difference
    cout << "\nThe difference of all the numbers is: "<<amt;
return 0;
   
    
   

}}

   

``` 

    enter code here
````

Comment: What value do you think `amt` has when you do `amt=number-number ;`?

Comment: i though it would go amt=first number i inputted subtract the second number i inputted itsbecause my teacher wanted to do a infinite subtrating calcu that will only stop when puting negative number and will subtract all the inputed number

Comment: I also eddited the question to give further explanation and fixed my grammar

Comment: What do you think the value of `number - number` is? What do you get if you subtract a number from itself?

Comment: @SweetEhanag *i though it would go amt=first number i inputted subtract the second number i inputted* -- You shouldn't guess what things will do.  The `number` is a single variable -- that's all it is, and that's all it will be.  So when you do `number-number`, you are substracting the value in `number` from the value in `number`, giving you a result of 0.

Comment: 0 but i cant think of the formula to use and i though amt=number-number would subtract all the numbers I though it would go like this 10-2 i thought it would subtract to the second number i inputted as value of number not 10-10

Comment: Did you get addition working without understanding how or why it works? You have made mistakes with subtraction that you didn't make there.

Comment: I need help since my teacherdidnt dicussed it and said to do it in our own i cant find a relevant information nor do i have a clue  on what code to put to make it like that since i new  ive only touched c++ last3 week since we started class

Comment: @SweetEhanag -- *i though amt=number-number would subtract all the numbers* -- No, all it does is what you see there -- it subtracts `number-number`, giving you 0.  I think the issue is that you assume the compiler knows your "logic", and can determine what you want to do.  That's not how it works -- it will do exactly as you wrote the program, not caring if the results are not what you want.

Comment: @SweetEhanag *I need help since my teacherdidnt dicussed it and said to do it in our own*  -- That is to see if you can think up the logic yourself.  I hate to break the news to you, but that's how you can tell if someone can think in discrete, logical steps that are required to become a programmer.  Also, it has nothing to do with C++ -- what other computer language would make the task easier?  You would have had the same issue with Python, C#, Java, JavaScript, you name it.

Comment: can anyone explain to me what code i need to put since only the looping was thougt to us and not the looping in subtraction addition and divition i only know how to subract it when it has limited numbers to be subtracted but in loopingi dont have a clue please explain it to me

Comment: To be more explicit: you only need to change *one character* to make your addition code become subtraction code.

Comment: or just a clue please

Comment: you mean the amt+=number to amt-=number??

Comment: This exercise is mostly about spotting a common pattern and repeating it. Later exercises will be about spotting common patterns and using functions (and sometimes classes) to avoid repeating them.

Comment: OWH WOW IM SO DUMB IM SORRY THX I GOT IT

Comment: Thx i got the answer correct meif im wrong i changed the one cin >> number; to cin >> number1; and amt=number-number1;

Comment: That would make the result "the last number subtracted from the first number, regardless of how many there are", which is not what you want. You didn't even try copying the addition code and changing `+` to `-`, did you? (The point of this exercise is that you should realize that all cases are identical, except for the arithmetical operation. The point is not to create a program that produces a particular output by improvising until it seems to work.)

Answer (score 1):

You are subtracting `number` from `number`:

```
amt = number - number; // Which is always 0
```

So that's why `amt == 0` always.

So just change your loop to this:

```
while (true) {

    cout << "Enter your number: ";
    cin >> number;

    if (number < 0) break;

    if (amt == 0) amt = number;
    else if (number >= 0) amt -= number;
}
```

What this does is that if `amt == 0`, then set `amt` to `number`. I have done this because as the default value of `amt` is `0` (due to `int amt = 0;`), when `amt == 0`, then we can assume that the user has entered the first number, and thus we can set `amt` to `number`. And then we can use -= operator, which basically means:

```
amt = amt - number;
```

But before all this, using `if (number < 0) break;` we can check if the user has entered a negative number, and if the user has entered a negative number, then the `break` keyword will break out of the `while` loop.

Comment: Hello would you mind explain it more elaborately?? sorry im new

Comment: I have tried to explain the solution in my edit. Hope it's clear :).

Comment: Uhm hello again can you make a division code???